# How to find a random item from a C# list that has a specific value?

Tags: c#, list, random

I'm trying to find an item from a list that has a field with a specific value; some entries will have the same value for this field, and in that case, I would like to return one of those at random. Does the List.Find function return one randomly if there are multiple entries that satisfy the criteria? The code below is what I currently have; if used on the same list multiple times, will it return the same entry every time if multiple satisfy the criteria? The list is large enough that I would prefer not to foreach through, build a list of everything that meets the criteria, and then randomly return one of those; I'm hoping to find a more efficient way. If that's not feasible for a List, is there another data structure more suited to this?

```
public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}

public Category CatByName(string nm)
        {
            string name = nm.ToUpper();
            return Categories.Find(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(name));
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to use another storage method you will have to iterate. Depending on how often you do this it might be worth building a Dictionary or another hash based collection to speed up the lookup.

Comment: Oh, btw, if `CategoryName` is a string (which it probably is), I wouldn't call something that matches `string.Contains` a *specific* value. To my best knowledge you can't (efficiently) hash for what substrings it contains unless you hash **every** possible one.

Comment: Why don't you remove the Category item in the Cateogories collection after finding it ? Improves the search (time) after every CatByName call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, you have to iterate the list.

Long answer: The probability to pick a certain item depends on the amount of items that match your criteria. Therefore, you have to scan the entire list.

What I would suggest to do is to get all matching items into a list and then take a random index. I find that more readable and less confusing than sorting by a random number.

```
public Category CatByName(string nm)
{
    string name = nm.ToUpper();
    var matching = Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(name)).ToList();
    if (matching.Count == 0)
    {
       return null;
    }
    Random rnd = new Random();
    return matching[rnd.Next(matching.Count)];
}
```

Comment: At least one answer without unnecessary Linq for the random part :)

Comment: When you say 'The probability to pick a certain item...', does that mean that some items will have a tendency to be picked more than others with Find, but it is semi-random?

Comment: @JacobHall No, I just mean that you need to know how many items fulfill your predicate in order to select a random one according to a uniform Distribution, which is usually the Translation of "a random one".

Answer (score 1):

Since `Find` will work only on `List<T>` you could use also `Where` which is applicable to `IEnumerable<T>`

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var selected = Categories.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(nm.ToUpper()));
var item = selected.Skip(rnd.Next(selected.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```